# What is $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ at $x = \pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given $\ln(y) = e^y\sin(x)$ and asked to calculate the value of $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ for $x = \pi$.

I solved to get $$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{ye^y\cos(x)}{1-e^yy\sin(x)}$$

So solving $\ln(y) = e^y\sin(\pi)$ I get $y=1$, but putting $(\pi,1)$ into the derivative I found is coming up with $e$, which is not being accepted by the webwork homework grader thingy(technical term) we have. So ... where am I going wrong?

Comment: You mean $(\pi,1)$. And $\cos\pi$ is $-1$ not $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must mean $(\pi,1)$ instead of $(1,\pi)$. Also the numerator should be $-\exp(1)$, because $\cos \pi = -1$. So, just add a negative sign to your answer and you should be good!

Comment: I did mean that, sorry, and ... I feel very sheepish, thanks XD

Comment: @Daniel Ball If you like an answer, you should consider accepting it, by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the delay. Thanks again.